# Overloading conflict with vector types __m128, __m256 in GCC

Tags: gcc, operator-overloading, sse, avx, mingw-w64

I've started playing around with AVX instructions on the new Intel's Sandy Bridge processor. I'm using GCC 4.5.2, TDM-GCC 64bit build of MinGW64.

I want to overload operator<< for ostream to be able to print out the vector types `__m256`, `__m128` etc to the console. But I'm running into an overloading conflict. The 2nd function in the following code produces an error "conflicts with previous declaration `void f(__vector(8) float)`":

```
void f(__m128 v) {
cout << 4;
}

void f(__m256 v) {
    cout << 8;
}
```

It seems that the compiler cannot distinguish between the two types and consideres them both `f(float __vector)`.

Is there a way around this? I haven't been able to find anything online. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled upon the answer when having a similar problem with function templates. In this case, the GCC error message actually suggested a solution:

**add `-fabi-version=4` compiler option.**

This solves my problem, and hopefully doesn't cause any issues when linking the standard libraries.

One can read more about ABI (Application Binary Interface) and GCC at [ABI Policy and Guidelines](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) and [ABI specification](http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html). ABI specifies how the functions names are mangled when the code is compiled into object files. Apparently, ABI version 3 used by GCC by default cannot distinguish between the various vector types.

Comment: Note that starting with gcc-5, this is not needed anymore as the default `-fabi-version` was changed.

Comment: Is that a fix to the issue GCC has with AVX / AVX2 code on Windows 64 Bit?

Answer (score 1):

I was unsatisfied with the solution of changing compiler ABI flags to solve this, so I went looking for a different solution. It seems they encountered this issue in writing the Eigen library - see this source file for details http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/SSE_2PacketMath_8h_source.html

My solution to this is a slightly tweaked version of theirs:

```
template <typename T, unsigned RegisterSize>
struct Register
{
    using ValueType = T;
    enum { Size = RegisterSize };

    inline operator T&() { return myValue; }
    inline operator const T&() const { return myValue; }
    inline Register() {}
    inline Register(const T & v) : myValue(v) {} // Not explicit
    inline Register & operator=(const T & v)
    {
        myValue = v;
        return *this;
    }

    T myValue;
};

using Register4 = Register<__m128, 4u>;
using Register8 = Register<__m256, 8u>;
// Could provide more declarations for __m128d, __m128i, etc. if needed
```

Using the above, you can overload on `Register4`, `Register8`, etc. or produce template functions taking `Register`s without running into linking issues and without changing ABI settings.